# Inner Join в SQL

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблица Users с полями id, First_Name, Last_Name. И есть таблица Birthday с полями Id и Date. Надо вывести Имя и фамилию человека с заданной датой рождения. Но сделать это надо через Inner Join. Пробовал сделать вот так:

```sql
SELECT Users.First_Name, Users.Last_Name FROM Users 
JOIN Birthday ON Users.Id = (SELECT Id FROM Birthday WHERE 
Birthday.Date = '1994-10-12');
```

Получаю правильные имя и фамилию, но в количестве строк, сколько есть в Birthday. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где надо поправить, чтобы на выходе была только одна запись. Или, может, есть возможность сделать как-то без дополнительного подзапроса.

Comment: удачи вам) Будут вопросы - задавайте)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
ON Users.Id = (SELECT Id FROM Birthday WHERE Birthday.Date = '1994-10-12')
```

Так лучше не делать. Результат подзапроса скорее всего будет не одной записью. Вообще если Вам в условии Join'а нужно будет сравнивать с множеством то корректнее это будет сделать так:

```sql
ON SOME_TABLE.SOME_FIELD IN (SELECT ...)
```

Но это не ваш случай. Вам следует соединять по идентификаторам. Т.е. просто:

```sql
INNER JOIN Birthday ON Users.Id = Birthday.Id
```

Также замечу что условие объединения может быть не одно.
Вы можете указать несколько условий после `ON` с использованием ключевого слова `AND`

```sql
INNER JOIN TABLE_1 ON TABLE_1.FIELD_1 = TABLE_2.FIELD_2 AND TABLE_1.FIELD_3 = TABLE_2.FIELD_4
```

Или же какие-то другие условия.

Условие выбора записей же можно указать в `WHERE`

```sql
WHERE Birthday.Date = '1994-10-12'
```

В WHERE вы можете указывать как условия для таблицы Users, так и для присоединенных таблиц.

Если у Вас возник вопрос в том, есть ли разница где указывать условие: в условии ON или же в WHERE, то отвечаю - разница есть, хотя в Вашем случае она незначительная.

**Результат:**

```sql
SELECT 
  Users.First_Name, 
  Users.Last_Name,
  Birthday.Date 
FROM Users
  INNER JOIN Birthday 
    ON Users.Id = Birthday.Id
WHERE Birthday.Date = '1994-10-12';
```

#### Замечания

- подзапрос был лишний
- добавил в выборку `Birthday.Date`
- в данном случае подразумевается что в таблице Birthday идентификатор равен идентификатору пользователя. В противном случае вам нужно еще полу UserId

Comment: Да, Id одинаковые. Спасибо большое, заработало. Что-то я не додумался использовать WHERE прямо в условии JOIN`а. На будущее буду знать.

Comment: @Drawen `WHERE` не внутри условия `JOIN`.  Это условие относится к `SELECT`.

Comment: Так в Users же нет поля Date, а SELECT запрашивает только Users

Comment: @Drawen, вы можете использовать присоединенные поля как в выборке, так и в условии WHERE

Comment: @Drawen, Вы же увидели присоединенную дату, после того как я ее добавил в выбранные поля?

Comment: Да, увидел. Спасибо еще раз, буду дальше постигать SQL